# Does Application Insights work in a Portable Class Library?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, portable-class-library, azure-application-insights

Seems to make sense to use a PCL with AI since a lot of the various projects all need to send the same data over to AI. I tried to add the Core package from nugget but it did not work.

Is there some technical reason that it will not work as a PCL that I do not understand ?

Otherwise Ill just have to paste the helper class in all the different projects

Comment: Could you post what did not work?.. Did you get some exception? Currently nuget has dotnet5.4 moniker. If that got resolved for your app it should bring PCL version of SDK.

Comment: As I recall it did not load the nugget package. So you are saying create a PCL and search for v5.4 and it should work ?  Ill check again when I am back at work next week. So you are saying that it should work as a PCL just fine right?

Comment: I tried nuget and it also did not work for me. lib\dotnet5.4 of that nuget does contain PCL version of Core that might work for you but since you cannot install it you probably better create a helper class. Also may be that would be interesting for you since you are saying you have different app types: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/transitioning-mobile-apps-from-application-insights-to-hockeyapp/